# how to use cursor.getString data for getResources()?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know this code will open dummytext.txt file on res/raw

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(
R.raw.dummytext);
```

But if filename `dummytext` is getting from search query like using this code-

```
int Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DETAILS);
details.setText(cursor.getString(Index));
```

Then how could i open dummytext file via InputStream inputStream command?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ResourceId by:

```
int dummyTextID = this.getResources().
    getIdentifier(cursor.getString(Index), "raw", getPackageName());
```

And then do:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(dummyTextID);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but file name dummytext will be getting by int Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DETAILS);
details.setText(cursor.getString(Index)); So why should i hardcode getIdentifier("dummytext_<whatever>", "raw", getPackageName()); ???

Comment: context is creating problem. context.getResources()

Comment: try change it to this.getResources(). Are you using Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Updated the answer, check again.